# Property does not exist on type '{}' AND Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, destructuring

I've a hook useAuth() that handles the user in context.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext_Provider"

//AuthContext has been declared: const AuthContext = createContext({});
const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext) 
}

export default useAuth
```

Now, I'm wondering how the h to call this function?

Below yields the error **Property 'auth' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)**

```
const { auth } = useAuth()
```

And if I try to add any kind of type *any*, *object*, *{}*, *React.Context* or even *{auth:{username:string}}* like below, i get another error saying: **Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)**

```
const { auth } = useAuth<any>()
```

Comment: yes `typescript` is trying to find `auth` inside `useAuth` , as you are `destructuring` it , but as i can see there is no `auth` you have defined anywhere , `so this error is expected one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});
```

Has no information about the type that the context contains. If you provide a default object, then you will get the types you need

```
const AuthContext = createContext({ auth: '' })
```

Or pass in a type:

```
type AuthContextType = {
    auth?: string
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>({})
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCEB2N0AeMANHAMZToCG+2eh8AvnAGZQQhwBElVZMXANwAoYTACeYdHACCyGAAs6+IgBVJ0gLyJhcPXCryFAfgBccVDCjAcAc2GNRZXJdlHlDONorVauFTAAPHKKHmoaAHwAFAiMAJSiAPSJIUr+ngpUqHAARujoOHAAJuhkADZUlEXmzjiuqWHw3rx+9EQx8SK1rmjoqV5wUXFeETr6cJQwyFCFvY1RDelEww6ihJCwxegshmXwvalOLvBIhopwzNoHRkPCQA)

Comment: Thanks! maybe I should start rewriting the end-components without references first to get these errors, before the bigger ones :S